# XMLDocument in parent changes to HtmlDocument in child opened with Window.open

Tags: javascript

I have a XMLDocument in parent window. When a open a child window using window.open and try to access the XMLDocument, it is retrived as DispHTMLDocument. Hence we I try add another XML using appendChild, it throws an exception "WrongDocument". How do I overcome this?

Browser: IE 11. Application is written to run in IE only!

Note: I am working on a legacy JS Framework and scope for changing the approach is very limited.

[image: Object in main page]

[image: Object is child page]